# Passive Combination of two Classifiers at the level of Class Labels

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-comparison, combinatorics, multi-class

I have three classifiers - 
1. Vision based classifier trained to detect class labels such as pedestrian and cars 
2. Radar based classifier to detect same class labels
3. Lidar based classifiers to detect the same classes

They have been independently developed and I do not have the access to previous training data or new data to test their performance.

What I have is their performance evaluation, True Positive rates that were estimated during the development process.

Those true positive rates show that camera offers better performance, followed by lidar and radar.

I would like to assign the class labels to the fused objects resulting from fusing all three sensors.

Is there anyway where I can increase the confidence on class label assignment ? Should I just use the vision class labels or is there any other way to improve the class label assignment ?

Comment: How do your TP rates look like? Can you recover the amount of non-TPs from them?

Comment: For a single class like cars - For camera, its like 95% and lidar is about 85% and radar at 70%